# Vagrant failed initialization on Mac OS Sierra Version 10.12.4

Tags: macos, vagrant

I have already installed: Vagrant and Virtualbox. I even tested the version with vagrant --version and it returns the current version (1.9.7). However, when I try to install a box on the terminal I get the following error message:

Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:

```
The plugins failed to load properly. The error message given is
shown below.

undefined method `activated' for VagrantPlugininspection::Plugin:Class
```

Could anyone please help me with this issue?

Comment: can you detail what you're doing on _when I try to install a box on the terminal_

Comment: I'm running the following command:  vagrant box add precise64 http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box

Comment: precise64 is a pretty old box, you should try with a most recent one and the new naming convention `vagrant box add ubuntu/trusty64` ? and if you really need precise box use `vagrant box add ubuntu/precise64`